# How to Change Block class for sales order status history tab

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml

Below is the Block

```
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
            </action>
```

I want to use my block class but not able to change it.

I have tried with below code.

```
<referenceBlock class="\Mymodule\MyBLock" name="order_history" >
```

But not working.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Override that class in your module.

Write this in di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History" type="your\yourmodule\Block\Adminhtml\<your path to your block class>" />
  </config>
```

Block class

```
namespace your\yourmodule\Block\Adminhtml\<your path to your block class>;

class <your class Name> extends \your\yourmodule\Block\Adminhtml\<your path to your block class>
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but that I already know but is there any alternate way to achieve this.